# Invalidate an answer when starting a bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

When one setup a bounty, one can choose several generic comment to be added under the bounty. This is one of them:

> **The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.**

It seems to me that this is justifying "changing the question after an answer is posted", which is not encouraged AFAIK. Am I getting it wrong? When would one use this comment "correctly"?

Comment: I had a similar experience. 1. I posted an answer to a question, 2. The answer did not get up-vote or acceptance few days, 3. I tried to communicate with the questioner by commenting to the question, 4. The questioner posted a bounty on the question by saying "Looking for answers from credible and/or official source", 5. It attracted several wrong answers and they are deleted after I pointed out their mistakes, 6. After the grace period ended, the bounty was cancelled, but the bounty attracted some upvotes on my answer.

Comment: travel SE certainly has reasons to use this. For example, ferry travel is becoming more and more impossible every passing year. Land routes through the Middle East are gone due to Syria. Iran might be opening up a little due to recent political agreements. Travelling advice to Crimea posted before 2014 March is certainly out of date.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The bounty reasons are the same throughout the network. This bounty reason is easy to understand on sites like Stack Overflow: Releases of new versions of a software package can make answers referring to an earlier release outdated, that's not an uncommon occurrence.

An analogous thing can happen in mathematics, a conjecture can be proven/disproven, sometimes even something that was accepted as a theorem turns out to be false. Of course these events are very rare in comparison to new software releases. In such cases, the "out-of-date" bounty reason is appropriate.

Changing the question after an answer was posted is - with some exceptions regarding clarification, or addition of constraints that were forgotten in the original post - strongly discouraged. Everywhere on the network.