# 2021 Election Results: Congratulations to our new moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The [2021 elections](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9) are over. By analyzing the [OpaSTV file](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/download-result/9) with the voting data, I'd like to welcome to the moderators' team the winners of the 2021 moderators elections::

- [Paramanand Singh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72031/paramanand-singh)
- [TheSimpliFire](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/471884/thesimplifire)

In the name of all the users on Mathematics SE, congratulations on your victory and welcome to the team!

We also want to thank [Michael Greinecker](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21674/michael-greinecker), who is stepping down today, for his many long years of service to this community. Thank you very much for all your hard work over the years.

Comment: congratulation @Paramanand Singh

Comment: I knew it: I never doubted you, @Asaf!!   Congratulations to the winners!

Comment: Sorry it took so long, there's that additional "review question" step before it actually get posted.

Comment: Congrats TheSimpliFire!!

Comment: Congrats to you too @ParamanandSingh, look forward to working with you and the rest of the moderation team.

Comment: Also congrats to Asaf for announcing results first!

Comment: Thanks for your service for so many years, on this site, @MichaelGreinecker !!

Comment: Congrats to the new moderators! No need for you guys to hang around here. We'll party just fine by ourselves. But you need to go sign the moderator agreement before the hazing ritual can start. Heehee...

Comment: Hah!  love it, @Jyrki!!

Comment: Seconding the thanks to Michael!

Comment: @TheSimpliFire congratulations Now you  are a moderator of two site

Comment: Pretty impressive, given you're overseeing two elections!   Thanks for your diligence and attention during this math.se election!   Great job!

Comment: Why is there a difference between “1,905 voted” on https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9 and “The number of voters is 1882” in https://www.opavote.com/reports/4713780039647232/0?style=txt ? For the two previous elections these numbers are identical.

Comment: Has math.se have two round one winners, when two positions have been open??

Comment: With all due respect to Michael and the already departed Daniel, I expect these two moderators to be more active and hands-on in their operation than the aforementioned duo, at least for the next year or so. I know a moderator's work often goes unnoticed and behind the scenes, but there was a lack of any kind of opinion or visible activity whatsoever from Michael and Daniel regarding EoQS or any of the other hot meta questions in the recent period. I think the entirety of last year has passed them by , and it's better that this election occurred and two very open and vocal mods are in.

Comment: This doesn't take away from Michael's meta contributions : two of his posts were answering the proposal to ban verbatim homework questions, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/proposal-ban-verbatim-homework-questions-which-have-no-accompanying-text/9196#9196), and a discussion on posting multiple questions at once, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one). There's [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28918/please-help-me-improve-question-on-cauchys-integral-formula/28920#28920) as well.

Comment: A summary of the voting data is [here](https://www.opavote.com/results/4713780039647232).

Comment: Well played to the other participants in this election i.e. ParclyTaxel and Christian Prince. Good luck for the next elections, whenever they come up.

Comment: Can you explain the discrepancy between “**1,905** voted” on https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9 and “The number of voters is **1882**” in https://www.opavote.com/reports/4713780039647232/0?style=txt ?

Comment: When a mod has to close a post by a mod :)

Comment: No one *had to* close this post, @user600016.   I think JNat handled the election well.  Asaf always gets a kick out closing as a dupe, any other report of election results, when he's already posted the results shortly before the others.  I'd consider this matter a sort of an ongoing challenge, and for humor and recreational reasons only.

Comment: Investigating, @MartinR — well spotted.

Comment: Has there ever been an earlier election in which two candidates surpassed the necessary "winner" line on folks first votes? (i.e., in the first round, where only the candidate listed first on voters ballots?)   Too bad we can't play out the second round, just to see exactly how emphatic the voters' voice.

Comment: @amWhy I don't have time to do this, but for your last point I'd imagine it is possible to export the ballot file (click on "Download Ballots" in [here](https://www.opavote.com/results/4713780039647232)) into Excel and plot a bar graph of second/third choices; note the first column is a dummy column and the first row can be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, @TheSimpliFire !   I imagine the second round would mostly reinforce each winner, as there were a lot of folks listing you both as 1, 2.   Again, thanks!

Comment: Yes indeed @amWhy It was just a light hearted joke. Sorry if anyone was offended.

Comment: No problem, @user600016  Thanks for the heads up! :-)

Comment: @JNat, while investigating [Martin R's question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34314/2021-election-results-congratulations-to-our-new-moderators#comment159008_34314) I found another election where [the OpaVote numbers doesn't match Stack Exchange's numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13).  Can we open another bug report into these inconsistencies.

Answer (score 63):

Thanks to everyone for participating in the elections irrespective of their votes.

I am humbled by your support and I think your trust will be a key asset in my role as a moderator.

Congratulations to TheSimpliFire!

Looking forward to work with the existing mod team to the best of my ability!

Comment: Congratulations and more !

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: @ParamanandSingh congrats, fellow Indian!!!

Answer (score 53):

I guess I'll also write an answer :P

Thank you to the community, especially those who have contributed to asking questions and voting during the election process! Very looking forward to join the moderation team and committing to what I have mentioned in my questionnaire answers.

Congratulations to Paramanand Singh, I hope you'll get enough sleep tonight!

Comment: Congratulations and more ! –

Comment: Congrats! I voted for you both last time and this time!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: @The SimpliFire, congrats!!! And yes, should we call in some guys to fetch a pizza as part of the celebration?? ( Just kidding, you see... and yeah, a hearty lot of good luck to you as you run about in this responsibility, sir!)... Btw I didn't understand why I couldn't vote... is it possible only for the 18+ category or what??

Comment: @Spectre voting only requires you to be 13+ (like any other usage of this site does), I don’t know why you couldn’t vote, maybe ask on [meta.se]

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica ahhh... nvm.. Afterall I am not into politics and related stuff, so yeah, I'd better come over for victory parties rather than vote someone up :D Thanks anyway